# MongoDB query for the most similar array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a bunch of documents in a MongoDB collection that has a fingerprint, that is made up of 8 booleans in a sequence. I would like to construct a query that will give me the documents that has between 7 to 8 of the booleans similar to my query in the same sequence.

So my query would be something in the line of: Find All documents that has the

```
fingerPrint = ["true", "false", "true", "true", "true", "true", "false", "true"   ]
```

The query would return both documents, since the first document has all the booleans in the sequence correct and the second document has 7 of the 8 booleans correct in the sequence.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5538e75c3cea103b25ff94a3"),
    "name" : "document1",
    "fingerPrint" : [
        "true",
        "false",
        "true",
        "true",
        "true",
        "true",
        "false",
        "true"
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5538e75c3cea103b25ff94a4"),
    "name" : "document2",
    "fingerPrint" : [
        "true",
        "false",
        "true",
        "true",
        "false",
        "true",
        "false",
        "true"
    ]
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Alternativly: Is there a better way of storing the bit array and be able to query the collection more optimally?

Comment: you should try storing the fingerprint as `{fingerprint : 10110101}`. It would save you strorage in the future and also would perform better in case of an index.